# Why is the assert statement not functioning as expected?

Tags: dart

I created some code that will count the number of occurrences of a character in a String. Here it is

```dart
void main() {
  print("1100011110000011".count(SingleChar('1')));
  print("1100011110000011".count(SingleChar('1135465321')));
  print("1100011110000011".count(SingleChar('')));
}

class StringCountArg{}
class CodeUnit extends StringCountArg{
  int codeUnit;
  CodeUnit(this.codeUnit);
}
class SingleChar extends StringCountArg{
  String string;
  SingleChar(this.string): assert(string.length == 1);
}
extension CharCounter on String {
  
  int count<T extends StringCountArg>(T r){
    if(r is CodeUnit){
      return codeUnits.where((cu) => cu == r.codeUnit).length;
    }else if(r is SingleChar){
      return codeUnits.where((cu) => cu == r.string.codeUnitAt(0)).length;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
}
```

I created a class called StringCountArg as the base type for the argument (because I want to be able to supply either a codeunit, OR a String with a single character already in it).

The first line in main executes fine. Returns 8 because there are 8 "1" characters.

The second line does **not** execute as expected. I would expect the `assert` statement to catch the long string, but it doesn't.

The third line fails because the assert statement again has not caught the improperly sized string and has tried to access the first codeunit of an empty string.

What's going on here that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the characters package in the pub (https://pub.dev/packages/characters) to understand the relationships between all the various "string" representations.  It might clear up your misunderstanding.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz My question isn't regarding the strings. It's regarding the `assert(string.length == 1)` apparently always passing even when the string is long or empty?

Comment: How are you running your program? `assert` is not executed unless debugging or running with `--enable-asserts`: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of running the code in dartpad, which has assert statements disabled. That issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/310)

If you are not running the code in dartpad and are experiencing this issue, try running dart with the `--enable-asserts` flag (note that it should be passed directly after dart and not after the file to run.

`dart --enable-asserts lib\main.dart`

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was going next.  Put `assert(false)` somewhere. :)